# best way to get return type from a popup window JavaFx

Tags: javafx, popupwindow, return-type

what the best way to get a return type from a popup window. im creating a popup window and that has fields that need to be filled in. i want to get the return type Person from these fields.

heres where i call the popup window.

```
Button addButton = new Button("Add Person to interested list");
AddPersonAdop adp = new AddPersonAdop();
addButton.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().add(adp.addButtonPerson()));
```

heres the popup window class

```
public class AddPersonAdop {

    private TextField personNameAdoption, personAddressAdoption, personNoAdoption, personEmailAdoption;

    public Person display()  {
        final Stage  window = new Stage();
        BorderPane bP = new BorderPane();

        window.setTitle("Add Person");

        Button addPerson = new Button("Add Selected Animal");
        addPerson.setOnAction(e -> {
            window.close();
            addButtonPerson();});

        Button closeButton = new Button("Close Window");
        closeButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());

        VBox vbox = new VBox(personFieldsAdoption(),  addPerson, closeButton);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll();


        bP.setCenter(vbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bP, 800,800);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        return addButtonPerson();

    }

    public GridPane personFieldsAdoption(){

        personNameAdoption = new TextField();
        personNameAdoption.setPromptText("Name");
        personNameAdoption.setMinWidth(75);

        personAddressAdoption = new TextField();
        personAddressAdoption.setPromptText("Address");
        personAddressAdoption.setMinWidth(75);

        personNoAdoption = new TextField();
        personNoAdoption.setPromptText("Phone Number");
        personNoAdoption.setMinWidth(75);

        personEmailAdoption = new TextField();
        personEmailAdoption.setPromptText("Email");
        personEmailAdoption.setMinWidth(75);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.centerShapeProperty();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        grid.addRow(0, CustomItems.label("Enter Persons Details"));
        grid.addRow(1, new Label("Person Name *"), new Label(" Address *"), new Label("Phone Number *"), new Label("Email *"));
        grid.addRow(2, personNameAdoption, personAddressAdoption, personNoAdoption, personEmailAdoption);

        return grid;
    }

    public Person addButtonPerson(){

        if(personNameAdoption.getText().isEmpty() || personAddressAdoption.getText().isEmpty() || personEmailAdoption.getText().isEmpty() || personNoAdoption.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            AlertBox.warn("Some Person Info Missing", "Please complete all Person mandatory fields");
            Person person = new Person("name","add","@", "999");
            return person;
        }
        else{
            Person person = new Person(personNameAdoption.getText(),personAddressAdoption.getText(),personEmailAdoption.getText(), personNoAdoption.getText());
            return person;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.showAndWait()` instead of `window.show()` in the `display()` method.

Then

```
addButton.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().add(adp.display()));
```